# Extracting zones of ones in a binary numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm looking for a way to extract zones of ones in a binary numpy array to put different values, for instance, for the following array:

```
x=[[0,1,1,0,0,0],
   [0,1,1,0,0,0],
   [0,1,0,0,0,0],
   [0,0,0,1,1,0],
   [0,0,1,1,1,0],
   [0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

Expected result:

```
x=[[0,2,2,0,0,0],
   [0,2,2,0,0,0],
   [0,2,0,0,0,0],
   [0,0,0,3,3,0],
   [0,0,3,3,3,0],
   [0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`scipy.ndimage.label`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.label.html):

```
x=[[0,1,1,0,0,0],
   [0,1,1,0,0,0],
   [0,1,0,0,0,0],
   [0,0,0,1,1,0],
   [0,0,1,1,1,0],
   [0,0,0,0,0,0]]

a = np.array(x)

from scipy.ndimage import label
b = label(a)[0]
```

output:

```
# b
array([[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

to start labeling from 2:

```
b = (label(a)[0]+1)*a
```

output:

```
array([[0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0],
       [0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```